# How to start, stop and restart rtorrent?

Tags: server, services, bittorrent, rtorrent

I just installed `rtorrent` on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 machine via `apt-get`.

How do I start | stop | restart the service?

Comment: have you tried `sudo service start rtorrent`?

Comment: `sudo service rtorrent start` that is, but yes, I've tried that. It just outputs `rtorrent: unrecognized service`. If I write `sudo service rto` and press tab it completes to `rtorrentInit.sh`. I don't know what that is, but I remember (from a guide that is long gone far off into the interwebs) that I wrote `rtorrent` and `stop`, but not in which order and whether there is another word in between. I did not write `rtorrentInit.sh` that first time.

Comment: Yeah, Thats what I meant. Have a look here: [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Dedicated Server rTorrent](http://www.torrent-invites.com/seedbox-tutorials/195434-ubuntu-12-04-lts-dedicated-server-rtorrent-rutorrent-installation-tutorial.html). The last 7-8 steps are about installing and starting rtorrent. Maybe it can shed some light.

Comment: I've already read that from top to bottom. But thank you anyways. For the moment I can get around with screen and just jump into rtorrent and quit from in there, but I'll leave this thread open if anyone happens to know the answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To start rtorrent, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
rtorrent
```

To stop <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
To quit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>

The above commands you do after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, in the rtorrent window.

For more information see the output of:

```
rtorrent -h
```

and/or see [Using rtorrent like a pro](http://harbhag.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/tutorial-using-rtorrent-on-linux-like-a-pro/)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I am afraid that I might have mixed up the instructions for this program with some other program, so exactly what I was looking for probably does not exist. I apologize for the trouble, but hope someone else will have use of this thread.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it can take a while for `rtorrent` to close all files and exit after `Ctrl`+`q` — it doesn't mean it wasn't the right combination.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is correct but does not specify how to perform a "safe" shutdown of the `rtorrent` service with a `systemctl` service script.

Most existing answers or scripts "kill" either the screen session or the `rtorrent` process itself. In doing so, they send a [`SIGINT (2)`](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Sending_signal_to_Processes)or `SIGQUIT (3)` signal which stops/kills the `rtorrent` process. The drawback is that typically the lock-file of `rtorrent` is not deleted because `rtorrent` was not shut down properly. Consequently, the next start of `rtorrent` would fail because of the persistent lock file.

Taking a look at the [source code of `rtorrent`](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/blob/master/src/signal_handler.cc) shows that it expects a `SIGTERM (15)`. Hence, considering a `systemctl` service script the stop command could look like:

```
ExecStop=/usr/bin/kill -s 15 \`pidof rtorrent`
```

If `pidof` is not available you can also use something like:

```
ps -A | grep "rtorrent" | awk '{print $1}'
```

- `ps` list the current processes
- `grep` extracts the rtorrent process particulars
- `awk` selects the pid and displays it to stdout

In case you need to wait until shutdown is complete, you can use `killall -w`. Note that:

> `killall` may wait forever if the signal was ignored, had no effect,
>   or if the process stays in zombie state (source: `man killall`).

Comment: `kill -s 15 \`pidof rtorrent\`` could be more simply `killall rtorrent` (15 or `SIGTERM` is the default signal sent by `kill` and `killall`).

Comment: Also, where in `signal_handler.cc` do you see that rtorrent expects SIGTERM to terminate itself gracefully? I only see signal generic signal handler management code but no actual signal handlers.

Comment: Should not that be: `/usr/bin/kill -n 15 \`pidof rtorrent\``  or `/usr/bin/kill -s SIGTERM \$(pidof rtorrent)` ?  You're mixing up signal names and numbers. --  From `man kill`, `kill -l` will actually give you the list of signal names and corresponding signal codes. -- Also note that although back ticks, as in `\`cmd\``, are not officially deprecated, I have read that `$(cmd)` is actually favored as clearer.

Comment: Don't forget about `pgrep` :) The command `pgrep rtorrent` returns just the PID, so no need for piping or parsing